# How to login to a remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, remote-server

I want to login to a remot machine from my machine so that i could access the nfs shares. 
I used the below command:

```
ssh -l salini 192.168.164.78
```

But now i get this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-34-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

584 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

Could not chdir to home directory /home/salini: No such file or directory
$
```

What does it mean?
I'm in a machine that has an IP  :  172.21.215.101

I want to log in to another machine with IP  :  192.168.164.78
and with user name: salini

How can i do it?

Please help me. Thank you.

Now I've run 'ssh' in debug. This is what i got:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.164.78 [192.168.164.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.164.78:22 as 'salini'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:m/cExZWCnjGc0Vr56HbDDMZRunfoBXkpwPWhZJKi3Qc
debug1: Host '192.168.164.78' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/test/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 192.168.164.78 ([192.168.164.78]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IN
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-34-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

584 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

    Could not chdir to home directory /home/salini: No such file or directory
    $
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not already logged on that machine? Could you try to run the command `hostname` and nslookup with the result of `hostname` to see the IP of the host you are connected to? You can also run `ifconfig` and check if the IP of one of the interfaces of your remote server match the one of your command

Comment: I checked the 'ifconfig' command and the IP's dont match.

Comment: Have you tried the hostname approach? From what I have read in your logs, it looks like your `/home/salini` disappeared from the server... you should ask your admin to recreate one. also could you run `ssh` in debug and send us the content? `ssh -v salini@192.168.164.78`

Comment: My current host name is : wsm-ela-inc6 . My server host name is : ela-native . Could you please explain how to run run ' ssh' in debug?

Comment: run this `ssh -v salini@192.168.164.78`

Comment: `debug1: Connecting to 192.168.164.78 [192.168.164.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.` means that you can reach the server (no network issue) and that your ssh client will initiate a connection on default port 22. No problem so far: then your client will try to authenticate you as `salini` look at `debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.164.78:22 as 'salini'`

Comment: Then it will go through the different authentication methods that are available: `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive` one after another In the end he will ask you for your password since he could not authenticate you by using kerberos, publickey `debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 192.168.164.78 ([192.168.164.78]:22).` 

You entered the password and you are now connected on the server

Comment: Now the only issue is that your `$HOMEDIR` has disappeared for some reasons...

`Could not chdir to home directory /home/salini: No such file or directory
    $ `

Comment: Is there a way to find out why it has disappeared? Any suggestions?

Comment: With your user and root user if you have access: try to run the commands: 
`history | grep /home/salini` or `history | grep salini` and try to look for a `rm command or a move` or a `zip`, `tar` or something. If your folder has been moved or archived you can restore it back. If it has been deleted it will be more difficult to get it back. Also you can use the command `last` to see who was connected at that time on the server. Good luck

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the verbose output of the ssh client, we found that:

```
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.164.78 [192.168.164.78] port 22. debug1: Connection established.
```

The server was reached (no network issue) and your ssh client will initiate a connection on default port 22.

```
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.164.78:22 as 'salini'
```

your client will try to authenticate you as `salini`
It will go through the different authentication methods that are available(one after another):

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
```

In the end he will ask you for your password since he could not authenticate you by using `kerberos`, `publickey`

```
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive Password: debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive). Authenticated to 192.168.164.78 ([192.168.164.78]:22).
```

You entered the password and you are now connected on the server

Now the only issue is that your `$HOMEDIR` has disappeared for some reasons...

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/salini: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out why it has disappeared? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Salu: answered as comment to your question ;-)

Comment: I ran the commands u gave and i got this: '-sh: 3: history: not found'

Comment: could you do `echo $SHELL`? If it is not outputting `bash` You might need to run `bash` and then run your `history`... The problem is that your user shell profile located in your home has also been destroyed... actually if you are not able to access to the root user and check the history from that point it will be difficult to find what happened... Basically it can only be you or someone with permissions to modify the `/home` folder example root that could have modify it.

Comment: There is no 'rm' or 'move' or 'zip' or 'tar' commands in the history. And also when i did `echo $SHELL` i got this : `/bin/sh
`

Comment: @salu: even in the root history? are you sure the machine was not reset or something? or your user deleted/recreated?

Comment: Thank you @Allan . I found out that my account had to be recreated. I recreated my account and now it is working great.